# Can we use "Do your Button" for "Close your button"?

Tags: meaning

In an English movie, I saw one lady tell another

> Your button is undone!

meaning *Your button is unbuttoned*.

So can we say "Do your button" to mean *Button your button*?

**EDIT**: For the reference, this dialogue is taken from the movie "Unfaithful". Script and the context can be seen [here](http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/u/unfaithful-script-transcript-diane-lane.html).

Comment: You _button_ a button to close a button. _Button_ is both a verb and a noun. (One could _fasten_ a button as well.) To open a garment, you _unbutton_ (or _unfasten_) the buttons.

Comment: @J.R., and to open a button?

Comment: @J.R. What do we *do* our math?

Comment: Whoever thought this was 'not a real question' could have posted 'the real answer.'

Comment: @J.R., at last how about doing a _button_ as I asked?

Comment: Mistu4u, I don't generally say "do your button," which is why I left my original comment. Also, for the record, I happen to agree with what @StoneyB said. Just because people don't use a certain word now doesn't mean that they won't in the future. Language evolves – that's a fact, not a joke. Twenty-five years ago, I'd never heard the expression "D'oh!" Now, thanks to one animated antihero, I hear it somewhat frequently, and it's even made its way into the [dictionary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/d-oh).

Comment: @Kris the point about "not a real question" is that there is no "real answer" http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10583/147247

Comment: @KateGregory A better reference would be '**What makes a question a "real" question** ' http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145678/171051

Comment: @Kris the question is an inquiry about the degree of idiomaticity of a particular English construction. Questions of this type are both practical and answerable, and are patently "actual" problems for non-native speakers, since knowing whether a particular construction is more or less idiomatic is needed to use the construction effectively. I would object to closing on "real question" grounds.

Comment: @jlovegren I would think you really meant that comment at those wanting to close the question. Thanks.

Comment: @KateGregory: "Yes" is an answer, as well as "No". And both, supported by a minimal amount of elaboration could be applied to this type of questions perfectly well, so I don't see your point.

Comment: I never declared this to be "not a real question". I simply pointed out that "hey, if you think it's not a real question you should post the real answer" is a nonsensical comment. By definition, if it's not a real question it doesn't have a real answer. Your point supports the contention that it is a real question. I haven't voted to close it, so you can assume I agree with you on that.

Comment: "In an English movie" - is that English language or English nationality? As you can see from the answers below, this is one instance where the most common British and American answers sound alien to one another.

Comment: That was an American movie.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is completely understandable to me as well, if not idiomatic.

I would add that a construction you are more likely to hear and use than

> "X your button" (where X signifies: do, fasten, button, button up, fix)

is

> "button your Y" (where Y signifies: shirt, pants, jacket, lip)

Answer (score 16):

In my experience, the common expression would be **do *up* your button**.  You might also hear *button up* if button is used as a verb.  I don't think you would hear native speakers say "open your button" or "close your button".

Answer (score 12):

*Button your button* is an unlikely thing for a speaker of British English to say. We’d say *Do your button up.*

*Button* itself is a verb as well as noun, but when used as such it, too, also often occurs with *up*.

Comment: I might say "do your button up" or "do up your button" but I might also replace "button" with whatever it's supposed to hold closed (eg "do your shirt up") unless that was unmentionable

Comment: In American, "button your button" is completely normal.

Comment: @The Photon. OK. Answer amended.

Comment: I think (speaking as an American) that "Do your button up" would be an unlikely thing for a speaker of General American English to say.

Answer (score 6):

"**Do**" in this case is simply a vague verb meaning "**fix what's wrong with**" your button. People talk like this all the time, especially us working class heroes. If your fly were open (either unzipped or unbuttoned), then someone who uses that type of expression would say "**Do your fly**" or "**Do your zipper**". It may not be a standard idiom, but it's perfectly understandable, and I wouldn't bat an eye were I to hear it.

I don't see why you can't use it when speaking to someone.

Comment: Obviously, however, the phantom downvoter doesn't like the idea, but what does he or she know beyond random mouse clicks?

Comment: You're quite right; it's perfectly clear and unobjectionable. On the other hand, I've never heard or seen it, and I'd never put it in a script for a native-speaker-of-English character of any age or class; it's the sort of thing I'd put in the mouth of a fluent non-native speaker. Perhaps I should have told OP, "Since you ask, *button* is the usual verb. But it's really not worth worrying about; work on verb tenses instead."

Comment: @StoneyB: You mean that your parents never said things like: "Hey, do your thingy, please." And then you say "Whatta ya mean,  'Do my thingy'?" "Your fly! Button yer goddam fly!" When my father wasn't calling me by the dog's name, or his brother's name, or my sister's name (I used to flabbergast him quite often, you see), he'd say things like that to me.

Comment: Nope. *Zip yourself up,* perhaps, but where I come from people generally pointed out the unsatisfactory circumstance — *Your fly's open* or *You're unzipped* — rather than enjoining me to repair it.

Comment: @BillFranke, thanks for the laugh!  I also grew up in a house where "do" was used for many tasks -you just needed to know the context.

Comment: @KristinaLopez: Thank you for having a sense of humor! That's something I miss around here. (B-O My parents were normally articulate, but sometimes they just couldn't find the words they needed. Happens to me too. Every so often I get the [whatchamecallits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whatchamacallit) and flounder around looking for the right expression but end up spluttering some gibberish, just like my old man did.

Comment: A Google Ngram returns no results for button/ed / fasten/ed / did / did up // his / my buttons. The zip seems all-conquering.

Answer (score 5):

Here in the US, I wouldn't use "button" as the noun.  I'd use the verb in one of many ways:

- Button yourself up  (Jacket or shirt)
- Button up your pants  (The button above the zipper)

And so on...

Comment: Interesting point! I like it!

Answer (score 4):

When one says that a button is undone, it is almost always understood that it is by accident that one of the buttons on a garment isn't buttoned. When a button gets unbuttoned by accident, you can say that, for example, *Your top button has come undone,* or *My button came undone and everyone could see and they laughed at me.*

If you order someone to button a button that has come undone, you can tell them *Fix your button.* I can only find one instance where *do* is used to mean "button." It is in a Parenting magazine in an article advising young parents on how to teach their children to groom themselves. If the child insists that the mother button his shirt for him, the mother is advised to tell the boy *Now I'll do a button, then you do a button.* Basically, *do your button* would probably only be appropriate to say in some kind of joint attention scenario where buttons are of high salience, and where buttoning a button is a kind of effortful activity.

For a non-native speaker, stick with *fix your button* or *button your button.*

Comment: *fix your button* maybe, but *button your button*?

Comment: Why not _button your button_? May not be great style, but it's clear and simple(minded) English, ain't it? _Button your lip_, _button your shirt_, _button your collar_, _button your blouse_, or _button your fly_ are probably all more normal and idiomatic. 'Richard Cory performs "You Better [Button Your Buttons](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TIe5DttY6ZM) ('Cause it's Getting Cold Outside)" on February 4, 2011 at J.W. Mitchell High School.' **NB: I do _not_ recommend this YouTube video.**